# How to show multiple value in single row in select option multiple box?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-select, multiple-select

I am working on a typical UI that contains multiple fields. But i am stuck in one situation.

**Here is the design:-**

[image: Screenshot 01]

It will be a Select Multiple Box but as it is visible that one row have two values. I think their is no HTML tag that could be added inside `<option></option>`. I also have to use the functionality of selecting or multiple selecting the rows.

Could it be possible in HTML/CSS or jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Shobhit, thanks for reply, is `span` tag supportable inside `option` tag in HTML?

Comment: You can use select2 plugin it support custom templating for a row in option. https://select2.github.io/examples.html#themes-templating-responsive-design

Comment: @SaurabhLP.. Just checked. IE doesn't support anything inside the 'option' tag. You can probably use list element to emulate the 'select' dropdown. Lots of templates available for that. *GOOGLE*

Comment: Hi R.K. Saini, i dnt seen any example like my question...

Comment: You can use span but you are not able to style it..

Comment: See this https://select2.github.io/examples.html#templating, this example use image and name of county same you can do.